# Protractor - select next sibling of the current element

Tags: angularjs, protractor

In my code there a list of elements (tr) selected with "protractor.By.repeater".
This list is looped using "forEach".

Within this loop, the element is clicked, and this click should trigger the inclusion of a new "tr" just after the clicked element.

I want to select that new line.

I used :

```
var nextRow = tr.$(protractor.By.xpath('following-sibling::tr'));
```

but then with :

```
                nextRow.isDisplayed(function(row){
                    console.log('row', row);
                });
```

it generates errors such as : " UnknownError: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to java.lang.String"

Is there another way to achieve what I want, i.e to select the next sibling of the current element ?

Or did I wrote something incorrect there ?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like you are missing a `.then` there and misinterpreted what [isDisplayed](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/api.md#api-webdriver-webelement-prototype-isdisplayed) does.

Code should be more like:

```
nextRow.isDisplayed().then(function(visible) {
  console.log('is displayed? ', visible);
});
```

Also your ElementFinder `nextRow` doesn't look quite alright, what is variable `tr` below? and Protractor `$` is an alias for `element(by.css` which takes a string argument, not a webdriver.Locator like you interpreted below, in your code:

```
var nextRow = tr.$(protractor.By.xpath('following-sibling::tr'));
```

So instead maybe you meant:

```
var tr = $('table tr.first'); // just guessing here since you didn't provide that code
var nextRow = tr.element(By.xpath('following-sibling::tr'));
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it was the missing "then". I dont know why, but "By.xpath" does not work in the setup I have here, I have really to use "protractor.By.xpath".

Comment: I suggest you upgrade Protractor to see if that fixes this last issue.

Answer (score 0):

Using Xpath selectors is not a better choice as it slows down the element finding mechanism.

I have designed a plugin to address this specific issues: [protractor-css-booster](https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-css-booster)

The plugin provides some handly locators to find out siblings in a better way and most importantly with CSS selector.

using this plugin, you can directly use:

```js
var nextRow = element(by.css('table tr.first')).element(By.followingSibling('tr'));
```

Hope, it will help you...

Comment: 5 years later... but actually your plugin look nice